# Spring XD missing modules

Tags: spring-xd

I install spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE and start in Spring XD in xd-signle mode, when I type the following command

**xd:>stream create --definition "time | log" --name ticktock --deploy**

I get the following result:

**Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'log' and type 'sink'**

When I type the following command:

**xd:> module list**

I get the following resul:

```
 Source             Processor      Sink                     Job
```

---

```
 gemfire                           gemfire-json-server      filejdbc
 gemfire-cq                        gemfire-server           hdfsjdbc
 jdbc                              jdbc                     jdbchdfs
 kafka                             rabbit                   sqoop
 rabbit                            redis
 twittersearch
 twitterstream
```

Some default modules are missed ? What happens ? Is there any other configuration to set before starting spring xd ?

Comment: I resolve the issue by my self. In XD_HOME I have <root-install-dir>\spring-xd\ in spite of <root-install-dir>\spring-xd\xd

Answer (score 0):

Check XD_HOME/modules/sink/log - Is this folder exist?